# Can Virus infected USB drive spread while booting Windows

Tags: windows, malware-detection

I want to know that, if I connected computer malware infected USB drive to a Window laptop, while its booting, that malware can spread on that PC? (without opening USB drive via file manager).

This laptop already installed ESET Internet security and run Windows 10 (64bit).

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: Windows 10, 64bit

Comment: This entirely depends on the malware.  If ESET is unaware or unable to detect the file then it could spread to the host pc.